# How to reduce the scale of the X axis between an interval, without changing the scale of the rest of the graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a graph whose values on the X axis **between 10-60 and 700-1100 have non-zero** values, and **between 60-700 it is zero**. I want to be able to make the X-axis range **between 60-700 values smaller** so that I can bring the two peaks closer together, and thus be able to graph better, **without changing the scale of X axis**. The axis scale on the **X axis is in logarithm**, and on the **Y axis it is linear**. The graphs are made from a data table in **.txt** format. Below is the code with the graph.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\begin{semilogxaxis}[
             height=3.5cm, 
             width=16cm,
             scale only axis, % makes the internal area of graph equals to= height x widthxmin=1,
             xmin=5,
             xmax=4000,
             ymin=0,
             ymax={1.1},
             axis x line=bottom,
             axis y line=left,
             yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick*100}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%},
             legend entries={ {CA-LH$_{phy}$} ,{CA-ER$_{phy}$}, {CA-ERLH$_{phy}$},{CA-LH$_{chem}$},{CA-ER$_{chem}$},{CA-ERLH$_{chem}$}},
             legend style={at={(1,0.67)}},
             title={$\theta \times T_g$ \ $\left(T_h=100K\right)$}]

      \addplot[blue,ultra thick] table[x=x, y={CA.LH.PHY},text special chars={\#}]{./07.04/Th=100K,Tg=variavel/Gr.txt};
      \addplot[fill=blue!20,draw=none,opacity=0.5,,forget plot] table[x=x, y={A.CA.LH.PHY},text special chars={\#}]{./07.04/Th=100K,Tg=variavel/Gr.txt} \closedcycle;

      %\addplot[orange,ultra thick] table[x=x, y={CA.ER.PHY},text special chars={\#}]{./07.04/Th=100K,Tg=variavel/Gr.txt};
    %  %\addplot[fill=orange!20,draw=none,opacity=0.5,forget plot] table[x=x, y={A.CA.ER.PHY},text special chars={\#}]{./07.04/Th=100K,Tg=variavel/Gr.txt}\closedcycle;

      %\addplot[gray,ultra thick] table[x=x, y={CA.LH+ER.PHY},text special chars={\#}]{./07.04/Th=100K,Tg=variavel/Gr.txt};
    %  %\addplot[fill=red!20,draw=none,opacity=0.5,forget plot] table[x=x, y={A.CA.LH+ER.PHY},text special chars={\#}]{./07.04/Th=100K,Tg=variavel/Gr.txt}\closedcycle;

    \addplot[green,ultra thick] table[x=x, y={CA.LH.CHEM},text special chars={\#}]{./07.04/Th=100K,Tg=variavel/Gr.txt};
    \addplot[fill=green!20,draw=none,opacity=0.5,forget plot] table[x=x, y={A.CA.LH.CHEM},text special chars={\#}]{./07.04/Th=100K,Tg=variavel/Gr.txt}\closedcycle;

    %  \addplot[cyan,ultra thick] table[x=x, y={CA.ER.CHEM},text special chars={\#}]{./07.04/Th=100K,Tg=variavel/Gr.txt};
    % %\addplot[fill=cyan!20,draw=none,opacity=0.5,forget plot] table[x=x, y={A.CA.ER.CHEM},text special chars={\#}]{./07.04/Th=100K,Tg=variavel/Gr.txt}\closedcycle;

    %   \addplot[magenta,ultra thick] table[x=x, y={CH4.LH},text special chars={\#}]{./07.04/Th=100K,Tg=variavel/Gr.txt};
    %  %\addplot[magenta,ultra thick] table[x=x, y={CH4.ER},text special chars={\#}]{./07.04/Th=100K,Tg=variavel/Gr.txt};
    %  %\addplot[magenta,ultra thick] table[x=x, y={CH4.LH+ER},text special chars={\#}]{./07.04/Th=100K,Tg=variavel/Gr.txt};

    %   \addplot[teal,ultra thick] table[x=x, y={C2H2.LH},text special chars={\#}]{./07.04/Th=100K,Tg=variavel/Gr.txt};
    %  %\addplot[teal,ultra thick] table[x=x, y={C2H2.ER},text special chars={\#}]{./07.04/Th=100K,Tg=variavel/Gr.txt};
    %  %\addplot[teal,ultra thick] table[x=x, y={C2H2.LH+ER},text special chars={\#}]{./07.04/Th=100K,Tg=variavel/Gr.txt};

    %   \addplot[purple,ultra thick] table[x=x, y={C2H4.LH},text special chars={\#}]{./07.04/Th=100K,Tg=variavel/Gr.txt};
    %  %\addplot[purple,ultra thick] table[x=x, y={C2H4.ER},text special chars={\#}]{./07.04/Th=100K,Tg=variavel/Gr.txt};
    %  %\addplot[puple,ultra thick] table[x=x, y={C2H4.LH+ER},text special chars={\#}]{./07.04/Th=100K,Tg=variavel/Gr.txt};

     

    \draw   [dashed,ultra thick,red] (25,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (25,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
    \draw   [dashed,ultra thick,red] (15,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (15,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
    \draw   [dashed,ultra thick,red] (19,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (19,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});

    \draw   [dashed,ultra thick,red] (1038,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (1038,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
    \draw   [dashed,ultra thick,red] (1557,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (1557,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
    \draw   [dashed,ultra thick,red] (757,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (757,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
    %\draw[ |<->|, thick] (axis cs:1,{2e-4}) -- (axis cs:25,{2e-4});
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here comes the *image of the Graph*[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[
name=plot1,
height=3.5cm, 
scale only axis,
xmin=5, xmax=70,
ymin=0, ymax=1.1,
axis x line=bottom, axis y line=left,
x axis line style={-},
xtick distance=10,
]
\addplot[red, thick, smooth] coordinates {(10,0) (20,0.4) (30,1) (40,1) (50,0.2) (60,0)};
\end{semilogxaxis}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[
name=plot2, at={($ (plot1.east) +(10pt,0)$)}, anchor=west,
height=3.5cm, 
scale only axis,
xmin=650, xmax=1150,
ymin=0, ymax=1.1,
axis x line=bottom, axis y line=none,
xtick distance=10,
]
\addplot[blue, thick, smooth] coordinates {(700,0) (800,0.4) (900,1) (1000,0.2) (1100,0)};
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with split x-axis and two peaks]

Comment: Question :  Is there a command to make the distance between the graphs equal to zero, to make it seam that they are one ?

Question 2 : Is it possible to select a domain for the graph when the points are loaded from an txt. file ? Example on the file data1.txt the x values go from 0-4000 on the table, but I want to draw the graph from the table between the interval 0-60 ?

Comment: A solution that I tough It my work, was:
1) shift all the values of the table from the second peak to make it closer to fist peak,
2) use the command xtick={0,10,20,50,60, 700,800,1000,1100,4000} so that it would wright this ticks, even if the x-axis scale does not pass through these points . Is it possible to make the ticks on the X axis to wright the values I want spaced the way I want?

Comment: `at={($ (plot1.east) +(10pt,0)$)}` purposefully makes `10pt` between the axis, to show the discontinuity. You can change it to `name=plot2, at=(plot1.east)` and drop the `calc` package`. You can plot some data from a file with e.g. `skip coords between index={⟨begin⟩}{⟨end⟩}` -see p. 396 in the manual.

Comment: You can make ticks *where* you want with `xtick={⟨coordinate list⟩}` and *label* them with what you want with `xticklabels={⟨label list⟩}` - but I would strongly advise against it. It is useful for named labels as `xtick={2.72, 3.14}` `xticklabels={$e$, $\pi$}` - it is not meant for making fake axis.

Comment: It would be really useful if your question included a precise description and e.g. a drawing of what you need. -edit your question, if you need further help.